# local variable access by workers in julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

Let's say I have some `data :: Vector{Float64}` and a function `f!(data::Vector{Float64}, i::Int)` that calculates some value from it, modifying it in the process.

```
answers = pmap([1,2,3,4]) do i
    f!(data, i)
end
```

Is this safe to do?  Does each worker have its own copy of `data`, or should I explicitly `copy(data)` on all workers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is safe to do and will create a closure that puts the `data` in the function and sends the function with the `data` to each process. If you use a [CachingPool](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/parallel/#Base.Distributed.CachingPool) it will make sure that `data` is only sent to each worker once (in Julia v0.7 and 1.0 this will be done by default).